# How to highlight a single value on a continuous color scale in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale-color-manual

A question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66274831/how-to-make-all-values-below-a-threshold-have-single-color-with-scale-continuous) shows how to declare some of the values missing. I have a similar problem except I wish to highlight a single value with a different color eg. `mpg = 20`. Ideally, I would like it to show up on the legend as well.

To be clear, I wish to highlight a specific value on the gradient.

I am reusing the code that was used in the other post to seed the effort. This code specifies the lower limit of the data but does not allow for an arbitrarily chosen value.

I was wondering if people know how to do this with our without using something like `scale_colour_gradientn`.

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- head(mtcars)
dat$model <- head(colnames(mtcars))
dat$is_low <- ifelse(dat$mpg < 20, TRUE, FALSE)

ggplot(dat, aes(x = model, y = mpg, fill = mpg)) +
    geom_col() + 
    scale_fill_continuous(limits=c(20,max(dat$mpg)))
```

Comment: As a general comment, you can replace `limits = c(20, max(dat$mpg))` with `limits = c(20, NA))` to automatically change the upper limit to the natural upper limit.

Comment: I was going to try to do this via something like `geom_col(aes(alpha=(mpg==20))) + scale_alpha(...)`, to have all of the bars except the focal one lighter/transparent, but so far I haven't found the right incantation to have the `alpha` scale apply to the fill component ...

Comment: (==20 won't work anyway because we need a range - no car in the data set has mpg *exactly* equal to 20 ...)

Answer (score 1):

This is adapted from the answer I gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58699545/11374827), but it requires some messing around with the palette.

This is a custom palette function that replaces the values between the `target` values with the `replace_colour`, but it requires to know the range of the data first. Note that the function isn't very user friendly, but it does the job.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

my_palette <- function(colours, target = c(20.5, 21.5), 
                       range = range(target), values = NULL,
                       replace_colour = "green") {
  target <- (target - range[1]) / diff(range)
  ramp <- scales::colour_ramp(colours)
  force(values)
  function(x) {
    # Decide what values to replace
    replace <- x > target[1] & x < target[2]
    if (length(x) == 0)
      return(character())
    if (!is.null(values)) {
      xs <- seq(0, 1, length.out = length(values))
      f <- stats::approxfun(values, xs)
      x <- f(x)
    }
    out <- ramp(x)
    # Actually replace values
    out[replace] <- replace_colour
    out
  }
}
```

You can then use that function with a custom scale as follows. I chose to highlight around 21 because 20 doesn't occur in `dat$mpg`.

```r
dat <- head(mtcars)
dat$model <- head(colnames(mtcars))
dat$is_low <- ifelse(dat$mpg < 20, TRUE, FALSE)

colours <- seq_gradient_pal("#132B43", "#56B1F7")(seq(0, 1, length.out = 12))

ggplot(dat, aes(x = model, y = mpg, fill = mpg)) +
  geom_col() +
  continuous_scale(
    "fill", "my_pal",
    my_palette(colours, range = range(dat$mpg), target = c(20.9, 21.1)),
    guide = guide_colourbar(nbin = 500) # Give guide plenty bins
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Applying this to log scaled values requires you to log scale all the input data to `my_palette` too.

```r
dat <- head(mtcars)
dat$model <- head(colnames(mtcars))
dat$mpg <- c(1e-6, 1e-4, 1e-2, 1e0, 1e2, 1e4)

colours <- seq_gradient_pal("#132B43", "#56B1F7")(seq(0, 1, length.out = 12))

ggplot(dat, aes(x = model, y = mpg, fill = mpg)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_log10() +
  continuous_scale(
    "fill", "my_pal", trans = "log10",
    my_palette(colours, range = log10(range(dat$mpg)), 
               target = log10(1e2) * c(0.9, 1.1)),
    guide = guide_colourbar(nbin = 500) # Give guide plenty bins
  )
```

Comment: Also I am unsure where the values to the x argument for the internally defined function come from

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example for log10 scales. To be fair, all continuous palettes from the scales package require input between 0-1 (see `?scales::gradient_n_pal()`, which I adapted), the function is just complying with what scales does. The internal function that is the result gets used as the scale's palette and during the mapping stage of plot building, the argument to that internal function is the input data fitted to a range of 0-1.

Comment: Perfect! This makes sense. Thanks.